# The import javafx cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I installed Eclipse IDE today on my Ubuntu Linux and then installed JavaFX using 'Install New Software' and when I created a javafx project, I got the following error in Main.java:

**The import javafx cannot be resolved.**

So, I listed the following directory to search for "jfxrt.jar":

```
ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext
```

But I didn't find "jfxrt.jar".

```
java -version
```

The output:

openjdk version "1.8.0_45-internal"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-internal-b14)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: AFAIK OpenJDK does not ship with JavaFX. You need to install OpenJFX on top of it. See https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Main

Comment: I went with installing JDK 8, JavaFX is installed with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

According to the [packages list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/openjfx) in *Ubuntu Vivid* there is a package named **openjfx**. This should be a candidate for what you're looking for:

> JavaFX/OpenJFX 8 - Rich client application platform for Java

You can install it via:

```
sudo apt-get install openjfx
```

It provides the [following JAR files](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/amd64/openjfx/filelist) to the OpenJDK installation on Ubuntu systems:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/ant-javafx.jar
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/lib/javafx-mx.jar
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why should you have to download the package manually? Isn't embedded inside jdk?

Comment: No, those files are distributed separately.

Comment: yeah i found it. javafx got separated from jdk since jdk11 i think

Comment: @Panagiss - Even for versions starting 8, OpenJDK does not contain javafx.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to set it up on Ubuntu *Linux* with *Maven*:

1) Install OpenJFX package, check where did it put the files.

```
      sudo apt install openjfx
      dpkg-query -L openjfx
```

You might end up with version for JDK 11. In which case, either follow with installing a new OpenJDK, or set a version of OpenJFX for JDK 8.

2) Put it to your Maven project as a `system`-scoped dependency.

> Note this is the lazy and not-so-nice way. Properly, you should install the jars like this:
>
> ```
> dpkg-query -L openjfx | grep -E '.jar$' | xargs -l -I{} \
>   mvn install:install-file -Dfile="{}" -DgroupId=javafx \
>     -DartifactId=$(echo $JAR | tr '.' '-') -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
> ```
>
> And then use it as a normal `compile-scoped` dependency.

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.source.level>1.8</project.source.level>
    <project.target.level>1.8</project.target.level>

    <javafx.dir>/usr/share/openjfx/lib</javafx.dir>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- JavaFx :
      sudo apt install openjfx
      dpkg-query -L openjfx
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${javafx.dir}/javafx.base.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${javafx.dir}/javafx.controls.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${javafx.dir}/javafx.fxml.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${javafx.dir}/javafx.graphics.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${javafx.dir}/javafx.media.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${javafx.dir}/javafx.swing.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javafx</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${javafx.dir}/javafx.web.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java Compiler 8 or above, do the following:

1. Right-click on project
2. Choose Build Path ----> Add Libraries

You will then be presented with the following screenshot below:

[image: Choose a JDK 8 or above]

Make sure you have downloaded and installed a JDK 8 or above

When you press the finish button, all Java FX errors in your code should disappear.

Note Prerequisites:

JDK 9 installed and tested on NetBeans 8.0.1

Answer (score 0):

A) Make sure that you are using a compatible JDK, like 1.8, AND

B) configure a compatible version of Java in the Eclipse Project Facets.

1. Right click on the Java project, select Properties
2. Select Project Facets, find Java, set version 1.8

For Java 11, this error also appears, as JavaFX has been removed from Java 11 and comes as standalone

More info:
https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/the-future-of-javafx-and-other-java-client-roadmap-updates

Comment: There are no facets in English Eclipse.