# Installed e(fx)clipse from the eclipse marketplace but running JavaFX application still gives error

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, efxclipse

So I downloaded the e(fx)clipse from the eclipse marketplace and when I click on New > Project > JavaFX project it creates a new project bundle but it already has errors in the import statements.

The errors say :

```
     The import javafx cannot be resolved
```

I am using Windows 10 , Jdk 12 and e(fx)clipse version 3.5.0 .

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Since you're using Java 12 (and I'm assuming JavaFX 11/12), see if https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Eclipse helps you.

Comment: What SDK version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn simple JavaFx application, you do not need e(fx) eclipse plugin necessarily. Still if you want to leverage the usage of e(fx), you can go through this following step by step tutorial.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/AddingE(fx)clipse_to_eclipse

While creating a program, make sure that jfxrt.jar is in the classpath. It will be available in the jdk installation.

Comment: Yeah I did that too and I've successfully added e(fx)clipse to eclipse and I can create a JavaFX project but when the project is created it already has some errors that look like this :

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/581820478549786654/583667879019413510/Screenshot_5.png?width=400&height=260

Comment: Install Javafx runtime, you can get from this link. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/installation/jfxpub-installation.htm

Comment: Install javafx based upon your java version.

Comment: You can check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32630354/the-import-javafx-cannot-be-resolved/34244725

Comment: It is abysmal how JavaFX has been treated post Java 9.